# Are we allowed to ask "What are the differences" questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11988547/561731) because I researched and did **not** find any reference to the differences anywhere online or on Stack Overflow.

I did find [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4564158/561731) which asked about two functions, one of which is the same as the questions I asked.

I am **not** asking a "since he asked it and got upvoted, why can't I ask it?"

I am asking if these types of questions are appropriate for Stack Overflow.

I have seen these types of questions get both good and bad responses (mostly good). So I am not sure why I am getting comments like:

> Seriously; even if it's not an Exact dupe (the answers do exist on SO regardless).... the online documentation is not good enough? SO is not a repository of docs. Do you have an issue with this code? problems? have you run into any bugs? no! this question needs to not exist.

on my question.

I would understand in the end if my question was closed, I am just curious on what should be done in general for these types of questions.

<sub><sup><sub><sup>I told myself I would not come back... but they just pull me back in....</sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) will apply to some (but not all) "what are the difference?" questions.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of your specific question, there is noting wrong with asking a question about comparing the differences between those specific functions.  While [Gorilla vs. Shark](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) will apply to many more vague "what are the differences?" questions, this one is sufficiently specific.  However, your questions has been closed as an exact duplicate because...well...there's an exact duplicate.  (You even linked to it in your question, you just didn't like the answers.)  It's worth noting that in the case of, "how are these two functions different?" you should make sure that you have done your due diligence first.  In many cases where a language has either duplicate functions, or very very similar functions, their differences will be documented, or you will find existing SO posts, blog posts, random articles, etc. discussing it.  If, after doing some research, you still feel there is information you need to learn, then it would be appropriate to ask the question.

If you find another question and just aren't satisfied with it's answers your best bet would be to add a bounty to that question.  It will allow you to possibly direct the answers to a more targeted area of that question, it will draw new attention to it, and it will encourage more detailed and involved answers than normal questions.

Comment: I did the research. I found no solution. therefore I asked the question.

Comment: The question the OP is referring to is asking about a *different* function than the one asked about in the "duplicate". They are somewhat related, but I don't think it's exactly the same.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA If you include the results of your research in the question, to indicate what you have found so far, you will be less likely of being accused of not doing your homework.  I also wasn't saying you didn't.  I was addressing the fact that others accused you of not doing the research, and indicated that they are right that you should do it.  I really couldn't say whether or not you have done the research.

Comment: @Servy did you even **read** my question?! I stated specifically what I had done and why I felt a new question was warranted about a *different* function!

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Your, "what have I done" appears to be limited to providing a link to a very, very similar SO question.  Additionally, in reading your summary of that question and the question itself, your summary seems rather incorrect.  In the linked thread, the primary difference between the two functions is stated that one is more strict in parsing and one is more loose, whereas your summary claims that the answers focused on it's uses with different radixes.  Given that the primary difference appears to be looseness in it's parsing, I would apply that same logic to 'ParseFloat'.